# BigCommerce API - How do I sort orders to return the most recent order first

Tags: bigcommerce

This seems like a simple question, maybe I am missing something but I can't seem to find the answer.

Using the BigCommerce API, how do I retrieve a list of orders sorted by most recent order first? I can't seem to find any way to specify how objects are sorted/ordered and by default it returns the oldest item first.

How do I retrieve a list of the 25 most recent orders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bigcommerce API v2 support sorting via `sort` GET parameter, try:

`/api/v2/orders?sort=date_created:desc&limit=25`

Comment: Awesome, this works. Is this documented anywhere? I swear I checked. Any other hidden gems?

Comment: Very late in the discussion , but yes it is documented [here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/orders#list-orders).